# How can I do ' IIF(MyColumn LIKE '%search%',1,0) ' in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to show 1 or 0 depending if a field in the json document has a specific word.

In SQL, I would use `IIF(MyColumn LIKE '%search%',1,0)`

How can I do it in `MongoDb`, under the `$project` section?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this (mongoplayground.net)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QKZ4AgJLESb "Click me!")?

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One example of returning a 0/1 field value, determined by a regex match or not, could be:

```js
db.collection.find({},
{
  "foundIt": {
    "$cond": [
      {
        "$regexMatch": {
          "input": "$key",
          "regex": "tion"
        }
      },
      1,
      0
    ]
  },
  "key": 1,
  "_id": 0
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QKZ4AgJLESb).